# Can Puppet change the inner file of .war?

Tags: puppet

First, I'm a newbie about Puppet (Configuration Management Tool).

-- And Please consider my poor English...

I got the order from my boss.

"Use Puppet, change the inner file of app.war"

The file is a property file that should be changed for each app server.
 (but included in app.war ; it's a constraint.)

The workflow is like this (short description).

1. GOCD makes the app.war (conf.properties already included)
2. Our custom tool delivers this app.war to nodes.
3. At each node, Puppet runs the scripts below (not real, just a naive example).

-=-=-

```
exec { 'unzip':
  command => 'gzip -d /temp/puppet/app.war',
  path    => '...',
}

exec { 'changefile':
  command => 'cp /temp/puppet/conf.properties /temp/puppet/app/conf/conf.properties',
  path    => '...',
  subscribe  => Exec['unzip'],
}

exec { 'zip':
  command => 'gzip /temp/puppet/app/ /temp/puppet/app.war',
  path    => '...',
  subscribe  => Exec['changefile'],
}
```

-=-=-

I just want to know about that this is a normal (or right or non-problematic) way to solve my situation.

Hmm... I think that Configuration Tools like Puppet are not suitable for this Application Deployment situation. (Though I'm a novice about CM.)

I tried to insist to use Rundeck, but I had no power (knowledge or executive).

Could you give me comments about this?

Thank you for all kind of comment...

Comment: A shell script would be more suitable than a Puppet manifest. It can perform the same tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Mr. Frank. :)

But my manager and her manager don't think so... :(

Comment: What exactly is the point of your question then?

Comment: Sorry for my foolish question. Yes, it seems like a non-technical question. Hmm... My original question is a something like this (Is this the correct way to change a config file using puppet? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984084/is-this-the-correct-way-to-change-a-config-file-using-puppet?rq=1).
I didn't know exactly Puppet's template. So, I'll try to solve the problem with it. Hmm... You can forget this question. Sorry again...